# Retrieve image URL from google-images-download results in Python

Tags: python-3.x, url

Is there a way to retrieve the image URLs from the images that are downloaded by  `google-images-download` (https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download)?

Here's some sample code:

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download 

response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()   #class instantiation

arguments = {"keywords"     : 'stackoverflow',
             "limit"        : 3,
             "print_urls"   : True,
             "size"         : ">2MP",
             }
paths = response.download(arguments)
```

And it prints:

> Item no.: 1 --> Item name = stackoverflow Evaluating... Starting
>   Download... Image URL:
>   https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_1904,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg
>   Completed Image ====> 1. so-logo-s.jpg Image URL:
>   https://kaggle2.blob.core.windows.net/datasets-images/152/327/43994ab64328703c9e656b04e6769947/dataset-original.jpg
>   Completed Image ====> 2. dataset-original.jpg Image URL:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/alOyI.png Completed Image ====> 3. aloyi.png
>
> Errors: 0

The paths variable conviently stores the paths to the downloaded files, and I would like to store the URLs that the files came from as well, but the only option the documentation provides is to print it. Is there a hidden way to retrieve the URLs, or can I capture the printed output?

Comment: OK I've made it work by catching the printed output in a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made it work. Probably not the cleanest solution, but it works.

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download 
import sys

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('URLS.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()

arguments = {"keywords"     : 'stackoverflow',
             "limit"        : 3,
             "print_urls"   : True,
             "size"         : ">2MP",
             }
paths = response.download(arguments)

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()

with open('URLS.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
f.close()

urls = []
for j in range(len(content)):
    if content[j][:9] == 'Completed':
        urls.append(content[j-1][11:-1])   
print(urls)
```

Answer (score 2):

Springing off of @Vicky Christina's answer, here's a Python 3 solution that avoids the intermediate writing to a file:

```py
from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper

from google_images_download import google_images_download
import sys


old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(), sys.stdout.encoding)


response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()

arguments = {
    "keywords": "stackoverflow",
    "limit": 3,
    "print_urls": True,
    "size": "large",
}
paths = response.download(arguments)

sys.stdout.seek(0)
output = sys.stdout.read()

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = old_stdout

for line in output.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith("Image URL:"):
        print(line.replace("Image URL: ", ""))
```